# I have created an indicator in Trading View. How do I run a scan over the whole market to find the stocks where the value of this indicator is 1?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator

I have created a simple indicator in Trading View. It has different colours referencing the values of the indicator it is derived from, (for visual aid) but simply has a value of one when I want to flag an entry signal.
The scanner in Trading View seems only to be able to scan for established indicators.
How do I run a scan over the whole market to find the stocks where the value of this custom indicator is 1?

Thanks

I tried to run a scan on similar indicators provided, but can't find how to incorporate mine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run that scanner with your script. It is not supported at the moment.

As a workaround, you can use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to request data from other symbols and timeframes. Then you can display that information in a table.

The maximum number of `security()` calls you can have in your script is 40. So, you cannot really scan the whole market with just one script. You can add the same script multiple times of course but that is not so convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I feared that might be the case. It seems a glaring weakness in an otherwise outstanding product (Trding View)